# How can I load a different style of a font as its bold font

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, bold

I am using the [Junicode Two Beta VF](https://github.com/psb1558/Junicode-font) typeface for my document. It comes with only two files, one for roman and one for italic. But if I run `fc-list`, I notice that the font includes a `bold` style through `Junicode Two Beta VF:style=Bold`. However, the `fontspec` package is looking for a bold font file, which I think is why the bold is not working.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum}
\setmainfont{Junicode Two Beta VF}

\begin{document}
\bfseries\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way for me to specify that the bold font should be the `style=Bold` version of the font?

Comment: Possibly section 2.2 of the fontspec doc has what you need.

Comment: I don't think Section 2.2 has what I need because I want to select by style, not by file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Junicode Two Beta VF is a variable font, the following solution worked for me.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum}

\setmainfont[
    BoldFont = *,
    BoldFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=600}}},
    BoldItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+axis={wght=600}}}
]{Junicode Two Beta VF}

\begin{document}
\bfseries\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```